# Custom NodeJS build including javascript modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp

is it somehow possible to build NodeJS together with some selected JavaScript modules? I believe that for native modules, I should be able to achieve this with node-gyp, but I have no idea how to do this for JavaScript modules. The main idea is to be able to use custom application without npm install.

I know that I can use any of the bundlers like pkg or nexe, but this has some drawbacks with respect to the development...

Thanks!

Comment: What's the drawback with `pkg` or `nexe` ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev: Well, one of them is the expected binary size (though I get the feeling that UPX would diminish the difference) and another one could be the need to package it over and over again with the new version of the app. It is for continuous delivery product and thus each MB counts... I know that those are not show stoppers but, it would be slightly better if I could achieve the custom build. It should be possible right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You're wanting it to go both ways. Have a package that contains everything and also to distribute a package that does not contain everything.

Comment: OK, I admit that the second point makes little sense. So in the end, the custom build with embedded JS makes sense for me only if it produces smaller executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include JS files as described in [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-with-external-core-modules).

Just add a link-module parameter.

```
> .\vcbuild link-module './myCustomModule.js'
```